# Remove Inactive User from Team Foundation Service Accounts group

Tags: tfs

I know we can add/remove users for Team Foundation Service Accounts group using TFSSecurity command

for example - tfssecurity /g- "[TEAM FOUNDATION]\Team Foundation Service Accounts" n:DOMAIN\username /server:https://tfs.mycompanydomain.com/tfs

When I try to remove inactive user (the AD user left the organization) I am getting Error: The identity cannot be resolved.

How can I remove inactive user from "Team Foundation Service Accounts" group. 
Any help would be highly appreciated.

TFS version : 2017

Comment: For that user which left the organization, did he also be removed or disabled in the AD? Or does he only be removed from TFS organization but still active in your AD?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since that user is inactive (the AD user left the organization).

Please execute the command `tfssecurity /imx “username” /collection:url`, then view the result to check this user existing in which group(s) in your collection. Ensure your removed this user from all the TFS groups.

If you are also not able to remove him from other group. You could try to use **User ID** instead of domain name.

`tfssecurity /g- "[TEAM FOUNDATION]\Team Foundation Service Accounts" n:userID /server:https://tfs.mycompanydomain.com/tfs`

The UserId  is stored in `Tfs_Configuration` database. 
If you want to know your ID, you could ask your TFS administrator to check the `[dbo].[tbl_Identity]` table to get your UserID.

Comment: Thanks for the database information. I just made a typo in the username.. it worked even with the domain name. Thanks for your help.